# Android CheckBox in Gridview recycle view issue

Tags: android

I have couple of TextViews, ImageViews, and checkbox in Gridview. My checkbox is working and I am able to check and uncheck but the problem is this is multiselect. If I check 1st checkbox and scroll down I see 4th, 7th, 10th item check boxes are also getting checked. I have read a lot and i believe this is because of recycle view. I am not sure how to fix this. All I want is if I click on 1st, and 6th check boxes only these two boxes should be checked. Below is my BaseAdapter code. I am new to android please help me with this.

```
public class test extends BaseAdapter {
public int itemSelected = 0;


private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
SparseBooleanArray checked;
HashMap<String, String> compareSelectionList1 = new HashMap<String, String>();

public test(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {

activity = a;
data=d;
inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
//return position;
return data.get(position);    
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
return position;
//return data.get(position); 
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater1 = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
              convertView = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.comparison_selection_list_row_del, parent, false);

              holder = new ViewHolder();             
              holder.txtBrandName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtBrandsn);
              holder.prodImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnSmallImage);
              holder.recFlagImg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnRecFlag);

              holder.txtPartNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtpartnumber);
              holder.txtNotes = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtnotes);

              holder.chkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chkBox);
                             holder.chkBox.setId(position);

              convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
              holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


compareSelectionList1 = data.get(position);
holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {   
   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
       if(isChecked) {
        holder.chkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.compselection_checked_btn);           
       } else {
        holder.chkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.compselection_btn);           
       }
   }
});

holder.txtBrandName.setText(compareSelectionList1.get("brands"));


holder.txtPartNumber.setText(compareSelectionList1.get("partnumbers"));
holder.txtNotes.setText(compareSelectionList1.get("footnotes"));
holder.txtNotes.setClickable(true);
holder.txtPartNumber.setClickable(true);
holder.id = position;

return convertView;   
}

}

");
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the checked state of the checkbox from your `holder` too. Otherwise, the checked state will be that of the recycled view.

I must say, that you implemented all this a bit akward, but coding along what you already have, something like this should work:

In your activity, define a member variable to remember which items are currently checked (note, that you'll have to save/restore the value of that variable in case the activity gets destroyed/recreated but that's out of scope here):

```
Set<Long> mCheckedItemPositions = new HashSet<Long>();
```

Extend your `OnCheckedChangeListener` like so, to keep track of the positions that are checked:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
   if(isChecked) {
    holder.chkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.compselection_checked_btn);
    // you use the ID field to hold the position
    mCheckedItemPositions.add(buttonView.getId());             
   } else {
    holder.chkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.compselection_btn);           
    mCheckedItemPositions.remove(buttonView.getId()); 
   }
```

}

And finally add this at the end of the `getView` method, right before the `return` statement in order to render checkboxes in correct state, according to `mCheckedPositions`:

```
if (mCheckedPositions.contains(holder.chkBox.getId()) {
    holder.chkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.compselection_checked_btn);
} else {
    holder.chkBox.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.compselection_btn);           
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ridcully. I am new to android and i would really appreciate if you could provide that code to me. please modify my code and post an updated code. thanks so much